# *** No rule to make target `src/main/jni/Build.config'. Stop

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, jniwrapper

Since I downgraded my NDK version to `14-16` (because of no GCC support in newer versions), I am facing this error
*** No rule to make target `src/main/jni/Build.config'. Stop

I can't understand why in the old versions of the NDK it says no such file or directory in `Android.mk` file this line `src/main/jni/Build.config`.

Comment: Do you run ndk-build from Android Studio, or on command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Here's a typical setup.

I don't know what's in your `src/main/jni/Build.config` file, pretty sure it is not used or needed (please show it's contents).

## .../app/build.gradle:

```
        externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }//ndkBuild
    }//externalNativeBuild
```

## .../app/src/main/jni/Application.mk:

```
#APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_STL := stlport_static
#APP_OPTIM := debug
```

## .../app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:

```
#=======================================================
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) #only call it ONCE !
#=======================================================
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE      := hello_world
    LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  hello_world.cpp

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#-------------------------------------------------------
```

## Links

[android-gcc-toolchain](https://github.com/sjitech/android-gcc-toolchain)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a file called `src/main/jni/Build.config` available to make.

Make sure you are in the right directory when run `ndk-build`.